# increase multiplier based on array index

Tags: arrays, for-loop, math

My iq isnt high enough to comeup with a formula for this. Say i have array of 200 elements. i have a set multiplier with which im multiplying each array element in a `for` loop.

```
    public float[] myArray = new float[200];
    public float multiplier = 150;
    public float multiplierFactor = 2;

    public void enhance()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++)
        {
            if(i > myArray.Length * 0.75f)
            {
                //  ... what to do here to multiplierFactor ...
            }
            myArray[i] *= (multiplier * multiplierFactor);
        }
    }
```

What i would like to do is: calculate multiplierFactor when 'i' has reached certain point in array (eg `(int)(i > myArray.Length * 0.75f)` ) such that start increasing the multiplierFactor from its original value of 1, go up to specified highest value (eg `multiplierFactor=2` so it goes from 1 to 2 or any specified value) then after max point is reached (eg 2) start decreasing the multiplier and go back to original value over the left over indexes of the array. So at the last element the multiplierFactor is again back to original value of 1. Kind of like a sine wave.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, you can try this. It should work:

```
if(i>= myArray.Length*0.75 && i<=myArray.Length*(0.75+0.25*0.5))
{
    #positive slope line equation for multiplierFactor
    multiplierFactor=1+((i+1-myArray.Length*0.75)/(myArray.Length*0.25*0.5))
}
else if(i>myArray.Length*(0.75+0.25*0.5))
{
    #negative slope line equation for multiplierFactor
    multiplierFactor=2-((i+1-myArray.Length*0.75)/(myArray.Length*0.25*0.5))
}
else
{
    multiplierFactor=1
}
```

Comment: sorry if i wasnt clear. i've edited the code. multiplierFactor is what is to be calculated. what the code will do is when 'i' reaches say 150 (when array is of 200 and 200*0.75=150), the multiplierFactor starts increasing from 1 in such a way that it reaches max value (2 in this case) when 'i' is 175 (halfway of the leftover elements) and start decreasing until it goes back to 1 on reaching the last element of the array.

Comment: Okay, I have updated my answer according to this. See if works. I think it should work. I basically used two line equations one with a positive slope and the other with a negative slope.